# Calculate total cost of items, based on bulk discount

Tags: c++, beginner

I've written a short program for one of my first exercise in C++.... I would like to get better suggestions to solve it, so hope you can help me :) And I hope this is the right session to ask...:)

> *Exercise:*
>
> **Input**: Pieces and price per piece. If pieces > 10, its 5% discount. If pieces>50, 10% discount
>
> **Output**: total price

Thank you a lot in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int stk, ep, gesamt;
cout << "Pieces?" << endl;
cin >> stk;
cout << "Price per Piece?" << endl;
cin >>ep;
if (stk>=10)
{
    if (stk>=50)
    //10% discount
    {
    gesamt=stk*ep;
    gesamt=gesamt - (gesamt*10)/100;
    goto stop;
    }
     else   //5% discount
    gesamt=stk*ep;
    gesamt=gesamt - (gesamt*5)/100;
    goto stop;
}

else gesamt=stk*ep;

stop:
    cout << gesamt << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3964927)

This can cause name collisions because it adds every name in the `std` namespace to the global namespace. For a small program like this one it's unlikely that you'll run into any problems (then again, [maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593548/3964927)) but it's best to get into the habit of using the `std::` prefix on names in the `std` namespace.

Alternatively, you can introduce [using declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) like `using std::cout;` to add specific names to the global namespace.

### Avoid duplicated code like `gesamt=stk*ep;`

That statement appears three times in your code. If that logic ever changes you'll need to make sure you change it everywhere, and you might miss one or more instances. Put that duplicated code in a function if necessary, or just write it once if possible.

### Indent for readability

None of the code in `main()` is indented, for example. It's easier to read your program if it's indented like this:

```
int main() {
  int stk, ep, gesamt;
  //...
}
```

### Use more whitespace for readability

E.g. use `gesamt = stk * ep;` instead of `gesamt=stk*ep;`

### Use descriptive variable names

The variable names seem to be in a different language (German?) but `stk` and `ep` in particular look like they are abbreviations or acronyms. I would prefer `pieces` for `stk` and `unit_price` for `ep`.

### Avoid `std::endl` in favor of `\n`

[`std::endl` flushes the stream, which can cause a loss in performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/3964927) In some cases you can also reduce calls to `operator<<` (e.g. `cout << "Pieces?" << endl;` becomes `cout << "Pieces?\n";`).

### Check the problem statement logic

The problem statement says to apply a 5% discount if pieces > 10 but you use `>=`. Your code applies a discount if pieces = 10 but the problem statement implies that the discount should *not* be applied in that case (only starting with pieces = 11).

### Use the appropriate type for variables

In this case, you probably need to use `float` or `double` for `ep` and `gesamt`. The price isn't necessarily an integer and neither is the total price if the discount is applied.

### Check your inputs for error conditions

For example, neither the number of pieces nor the unit price should be negative. Check for these error conditions and handle them appropriately (output an error message, throw an exception, ask for a new input, etc.).

### [Avoid unnecessary `goto` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379172/3964927)

`goto` is generally not needed, and that is the case in your program. Your program will reach the `stop` statement after entering the various `if`/`else` clauses.

## Result

Here's the end result of your program with the above suggestions (I've also made the code more concise in some cases, e.g. by the use of the [`*=` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) to multiply a number by itself):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int pieces;
    double unit_price;
    double gesamt;

    std::cout << "Pieces?\n";
    std::cin >> pieces;

    if (pieces < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot have negative pieces!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Price per Piece?\n";
    std::cin >> unit_price;

    if (unit_price < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot have negative unit price!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    // Calculate total price
    gesamt = pieces * unit_price;

    // Apply discount, if applicable
    if (pieces > 10)
    {
        if (pieces > 50)
        //10% discount
        {
        gesamt *= 0.9;
        }
        else   //5% discount
        {
        gesamt *= 0.95;
        }
    }

    std::cout << gesamt << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Missing braces leads to use of goto

Your code here is missing braces for the else case:

> ```
> if (stk>=50)
> //10% discount
> {
> gesamt=stk*ep;
> gesamt=gesamt - (gesamt*10)/100;
> goto stop;
> }
>  else   //5% discount
> gesamt=stk*ep;
> gesamt=gesamt - (gesamt*5)/100;
> goto stop;
> ```

The only reason this code works is because you have a `goto stop` in the first case.  If you just used braces properly, you wouldn't need those `goto` statements.  Also, you can also get rid of the outer if statement and end up with this:

```
gesamt=stk*ep;
if (stk > 50)
{
    //10% discount
    gesamt -= (gesamt*10)/100;
}
else if (stk > 10)
{
    //5% discount
    gesamt -= (gesamt*5)/100;
}
cout << gesamt << endl;
```